# Serviço Windows em Node

Tags: node.js, windows-service

Queria fazer um serviço windows usando Node, já que é uma tecnologia muito interessante que estou aprendendo. Então em minha pesquisa encontrei várias referências ao [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows).

Achei interessante, funcionou muito bem. No entanto, o que me preocupa é que eu não vi como fazer a distribuição do arquivo fechado. Meu script ficaria aberto, sendo possível ler o meu código e isso me desagrada.

Existe uma forma de eu conseguir montar um serviço windows usando node e empacotá-lo num executável?

Comment: Na verdade, não!
O que ele gera é um executável já pronto. Achei que o node estava por trás, mantendo meu js em memória.

Answer (score -1):

Podes usar [NW.js](https://nwjs.io) para compilar um executável multi-plataforma (Windows, Linux e Mac) baseado em `nodejs` e em seu fonte fazer uma chamada para o pacote **[os-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-service)** (que também é multi-plataforma) e configurar conforme sua necessidade isso deve resolver.

[Documentação para compilar com NW.js](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Package%20and%20Distribute/)

[Exemplo de uso de os-service](https://github.com/stephenwvickers/node-os-service/blob/master/example/periodic-logger.js)

Comment: Obrigado. Vou testar